# Why do sometimes I get "not a known element" warning?

Tags: angular, unit-testing, jasmine, karma-runner

I have a service which I want to test using Karma and Jasmine.

*title.service.spec*

```
import { TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { UserPanelComponent } from '../layout/user-panel/user-panel.component';
import { MatExpansionModule } from '@angular/material/expansion';
import { TitleService } from './title.service';

describe('TitleService', () => {
  beforeEach(() => TestBed.configureTestingModule({
    declarations: [ UserPanelComponent ],
    imports: [ MatExpansionModule ],
  }));

  it('should be created', () => {
    const service: TitleService = TestBed.get(TitleService);
    expect(service).toBeTruthy();
  });
});
```

*title.service.ts*

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class TitleService {
 private Value;
    constructor() {
        this.Value = 'shiny beautiful string';
    }
    setValue(val) {
        this.Value = val;
    }
    getValue() {
        return this.Value ;
    }
}
```

I run tests and everything is fine. The output:

```
  TitleService
    √ should be created
```

I do another testing and I get this:

```
  TitleService
    √ should be created
WARN LOG: ''mat-expansion-panel' is not a known element:
1. If 'mat-expansion-panel' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'mat-expansion-panel' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message.'
WARN: ''mat-expansion-panel' is not a known element:
1. If 'mat-expansion-panel' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'mat-expansion-panel' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message.'
WARN LOG: ''mat-expansion-panel-header' is not a known element:
1. If 'mat-expansion-panel-header' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'mat-expansion-panel-header' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message.'
WARN: ''mat-expansion-panel-header' is not a known element:
1. If 'mat-expansion-panel-header' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'mat-expansion-panel-header' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message.'
WARN LOG: ''mat-panel-description' is not a known element:
1. If 'mat-panel-description' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'mat-panel-description' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message.'
WARN: ''mat-panel-description' is not a known element:
1. If 'mat-panel-description' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'mat-panel-description' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message.'
```

So to sum up, warnings don't appear every time when testing. Why? How to get rid of them permanently?

Comment: have you imported MatExpansionModule in your applications module file?

Comment: you probably have another test somewhere where within the spec file you are not importing the `mat-panel-description`

Comment: The issue is that you are unit testing, and have therefore not imported MatExpansionModule. BUT YOU ARE CORRECT NOT TO! Proper unit tests __mock__ all dependencies. One possible approach is to create mock components (which are simply components with empty templates) in order to avoid the above warning messages. If you do this, I suggest that you also add the appropriate `@Input` to those mock components to avoid __all__ warnings. Your other option is simply to ignore the warnings, which isn't _really_ a big deal.

Comment: Yeah, like others said, it's a missing import. Try to run each test alone by using jasmine `fdescribe` one at a time, to sort this out.

Comment: Just noticed you're declaring a component and importing a module although you're testing a service. Don't do that (unless you're integration testing, of course).